# I want intent imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-webview, android-imageview

i want intent imageview to new activity. my imageview use xmlparser. but my app force close if i click imageview.

this is my code :

```
   thumb_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 String title = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textURL)).getText().toString();
                 String date = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateURL)).getText().toString();
                 String body = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.bodyURL)).getText().toString();
                 ImageView thumb_image=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ImageURL); // thumb image
                 thumb_image.buildDrawingCache();
                 Bitmap image= thumb_image.getDrawingCache();
                  Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                 extras.putParcelable(KEY_IMAGEURL, image);
                 // Starting new intent
                 Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                 i.putExtra(KEY_HEADLINE, title);
                 i.putExtra(KEY_ARTICLEDATE, date);
                 i.putExtra(KEY_BODY,body);
                 i.putExtras(extras);

                 startActivity(i);
```

my code on singlemenuactivity

```
   Intent in = getIntent();
Bundle bun = in.getExtras();

 //Get XML values from previous intent
String headline = bun.getString(KEY_HEADLINE);
String date = bun.getString(KEY_ARTICLEDATE);
String Body = bun.getString(KEY_BODY);
//String image = bun.getString(KEY_IMAGEURL);
Bitmap image = (Bitmap) bun.getParcelable(KEY_IMAGEURL);
  WebView browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);

String HTML = ......................;
browser.loadData(HTML, "text/html", "utf-8");
```

this is logcat my app

```
          12-16 16:10:46.017: E/dalvikvm(19543): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1537K, 19% free 10221K/12579K, paused 4ms+5ms
          12-16 16:10:46.017: I/dalvikvm-heap(19543): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.719MB for 660976-byte allocation
          12-16 16:10:46.064: E/dalvikvm(19543): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 19% free 10866K/13283K, paused 2ms+2ms
          12-16 16:10:46.118: D/webviewglue(19543): nativeDestroy view: 0x9683f0
          12-16 16:10:46.126: D/webhistory(19543): Writing Form data else {} Tag
          12-16 16:10:46.126: D/webhistory(19543): Writing Form data else {} Tag
          12-16 16:10:46.173: I/dalvikvm(19602): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 8...
```

Comment: your initilize your `thumb_image` inside your click event. post your full logcat.

Comment: that is my full logcat

Comment: Try my answer you can get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid this buildDrawingCache() Method
according to the android developer documentation

[Build Drawing Cache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#buildDrawingCache%28%29)

calling this method will increase memory usage and cause the view to be rendered in software once, thus negatively impacting performance.
Try another method to pass image url or image data on another activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Change your bitmap codeing like this..

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) thumb_image.getDrawable());
Bitmap bitmap1 = bitmapDrawable .getBitmap();
```

**Example**

```
thumb_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                 String title = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textURL)).getText().toString();
                 String date = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.dateURL)).getText().toString();
                 String body = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.bodyURL)).getText().toString();
                 BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) thumb_image.getDrawable());
                 Bitmap image = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();      
                 Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                 extras.putParcelable(KEY_IMAGEURL, image);
                 // Starting new intent
                 Intent i = new Intent(this, SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                 i.putExtra(KEY_HEADLINE, title);
                 i.putExtra(KEY_ARTICLEDATE, date);
                 i.putExtra(KEY_BODY,body);
                 i.putExtras(extras);

                 startActivity(i);
            }
});
```

Comment: my app still force close @Tamilan

Comment: @user3086099 what is the line number **33** in `SingleMenuItemActivity.java` and also post that class